Using vpasolve to solve equation in matrix form
image from MATLAB to illustrate the error
I am writing code to solve the well-known equation in matrix form, F = KX to solve a finite element problem. I have resorted the equation to get all the variables on the one side by adding negative eye matrix beside K matrix and initiating another column vector to contain X then F below. I am stuck on how to introduce the unknown variables into MATLAB and finding the proper way to solve this equation so the output can be a matrix of numerical values. Below is the code and associated error:
% ____ Solving Section ____ %
% Initialize the global stiffness matrix and force vector
% K_global is given
% X is  defined as U_global in this code

K_global_2 = sym ([K_global,-1*eye(2*numNodes)]);
U_F = sym([U_global;F_global]);
% Define symbolic variables for U_global and F_global 
eqn= K_global_2 * U_F == sym(zeros(2 * numNodes, 1));
% Solve the system using vpasolve
solution = vpasolve(eqn, U_F);

% Extract the solved displacements and forces
U_global_solved = solution.U_global;
F_global_solved = solution.F_global;

I am getting this error:
Error using sym.getEqnsVars>checkVariables (line 98)
Second argument must be a vector of symbolic variables.

However, U_F is assigned as sym in the workplace as you can see in the attached image
I tried to solve equation of F = KX in matrix form. I used solve, vpasolve, linsolve, but couldn't reach any results. I am excepting the out as vector column of numbers or numerical values which is U_F. I do not know what the source of this error is.
